# Amazon SQS region from EC2 Instance

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

If I create SQS queue from an EC2 instance without specifying the region in the API call, in which region will the queue be created.

When I run

`boto.sqs.regions()`

I get 4 regions from an NON ec2 machine, I get

`[RegionInfo:us-east-1, RegionInfo:eu-west-1, RegionInfo:us-west-1, RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1]`

from a EC2 machine in the Asia Pacific Region I get

`[RegionInfo:us-east-1, RegionInfo:eu-west-1, RegionInfo:us-west-1]`

Does Amazon set region of SQS based on the EC2 instance region. Is there a way to access other region Queues?

I am using the python Boto library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the boto library, you have to specify which region to connect to or else it defaults to US-EAST region. The old version of boto python library (1.9) did not have the Southeast Asia region and hence the above problem.